# How would I provide a standard user to give privileges of a salesforce administrator?

Tags: user-management, permission-sets

[image]I am new to salesforce. How should I provide a particular user with a standard user profile to give full admin access.I just want want only this user to have the admin access and not rest of the users since there are 10 users with standard user profile.

Kindly help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a permission set and you can assign that to that user. Here are the steps you can follow.

1. Create Permission set
2. Grant all the permissions you want to give to that user.
3. Assign that permission set to your user.

You can refer following documents

[What is permission set](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_overview.htm&language=en)

[How to assign permission set](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_assigning.htm)

Comment: I have created a permission set where system permissions in permission set have been given to a particular user. How would I make sure that the user who has been assigned the permission set can customize contact and account page layout.(manage contact and account page layout).

Comment: go to the detail page of that user. click on Login button, system will allow to login as that user.

Comment: Hi Himanshu,the user is still not able to edit the contact page layout when I login with her access.

Comment: How would I make the user able to edit the contact page layout when I have already given her permission set access to edit the contact and account page layout. When she tries to edit the contact page,it shows that she does not have privilege to edit the contact page layout.

Comment: You need to add two permission to that permission set.

1. Customize application
2. View Setup and Configuration

Comment: Hi Himanshu, there isn't any option for customize application however view setup and configuration is already checked for the user. Can you tell me the exact navigation where would I find the customize application in permission set.

Comment: Open permission set.. select system permissions--> click edit -> check both checkbox.

Comment: There isn't any option for customize application under system permissions.There is only View Setup and Configuration option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30429/discussion-between-kunal-gupta-and-himanshu).